# How to delete all SQL rows which are in datagrid?

Tags: vb.net

I have datagridview and textbox. I type item code and search from SQL and data enter in datagridview. Now how to delete all items from SQL which are in datagridview by item code.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show some code

Comment: What DB are you using?  What SQL have you tried?  Have you set up your connection to the DB?  In other words, include details.

Comment: I have setup SQL connection and I have two codes one for search from stock table and second for insert in sale table. I am unable to post both codes here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which you can download the full project [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjjHQSuCDsY2z1q7eq). Note a script is in the project to generate the table used in the code sample.

In this example shown below is part of the code. Form load event loads a DataTable to a BindingSource and the BindingSource becomes the DataSource of the DataGridView.

The remove operation, first check if the user entered an account number, then check to see if the account is in the DataGridView (even better is to check the underlying database table if this is a multi-user environment with another SQL SELECT statement). If the account is found, ask if they really want to remove the record where the Question dialog defaults to No rather than yes. If the confirm by pressing yes run the DELETE statement and return true if one record was removed else return false.

Back in the form if the operation was successful remove the record from the DataGridView using a find in the BindingSource.

**Caveats**:
This could all be done in a form but it's better to separate data operations from form operations in general and makes the code usable in other forms and if the data class is in a class project can be used in other projects.

As indicated above, you might want to check the record to delete from the database rather than the currently viewed data if a multi-user environment.

Optionally provide a auto-complete TextBox or ComboBox populated with existing account numbers. This helps to avoid guess work by the user.

Optionally provide a method from a button click event to remove the current record.

**Form code** which has a DataGridView, TextBox and Button.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private peopleBindingSource As New BindingSource
    Private operations as New Operations
    Private Sub accountDeleteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles accountDeleteButton.Click

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountNumberTextBox.Text) Then

            Dim result = CType(peopleBindingSource.DataSource, DataTable).
                    AsEnumerable().
                    FirstOrDefault(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Account") = accountNumberTextBox.Text)

            If result Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to find account in the current loaded data.")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If My.Dialogs.Question($"Remove account '{accountNumberTextBox.Text}'") Then
                If operations.RemoveByAccountNumber(accountNumberTextBox.Text) Then
                    peopleBindingSource.RemoveAt(peopleBindingSource.Find("Account", accountNumberTextBox.Text))
                Else
                    If Not operations.IsSuccessFul Then
                        MessageBox.Show($"Encounter errors{Environment.NewLine}{operations.LastExceptionMessage}")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        peopleBindingSource.DataSource = operations.Read
        If operations.IsSuccessFul Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = peopleBindingSource
        Else
            accountDeleteButton.Enabled = False
            MessageBox.Show($"Encounter errors{Environment.NewLine}{operations.LastExceptionMessage}")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Data class**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Operations
    Inherits BaseSqlServerConnection

    Public Sub New()
        DefaultCatalog = "DeleteExample"
    End Sub
    Public Function Read() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        mHasException = False
        Dim selectStatement = "SELECT id,FirstName,LastName,Account FROM dbo.Person"
        Using cn = New SqlConnection() With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand() With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = selectStatement}

                Try
                    cn.Open()
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    dt.Columns("id").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
                Catch ex As Exception
                    mHasException = True
                    mLastException = ex
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using

        Return dt

    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Remove account if found and return true
    ''' Account not found, return false
    ''' Error throw, return false
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="accountNumber"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function RemoveByAccountNumber(accountNumber As String) As Boolean

        mHasException = False
        Dim deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM dbo.Person WHERE Account = @AccountNumber"
        Using cn = New SqlConnection() With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand() With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = deleteStatement}
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber)
                Try
                    cn.Open()
                    Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1
                Catch ex As Exception
                    mHasException = True
                    mLastException = ex
                    Return False
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using

    End Function

End Class
```